# Understanding the memory growth of a process in svmon's "Inuse" column on an AIX 7 system

Tags: memory, aix

Our company has developed a process where I had to add a new method that implies some memory overhead. I'm required to measure it. So I went to `svmon` and applied it to my process. This is the original memory consumption profile:

```
 $ svmon -P my_pid -O summary=basic,unit=KB
 Pid      Command          Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual
 4391290  ?????            596384    41900        0   577708
```

Then I made a request so my "new method" is fired and the output changes to:

```
 $ svmon -P my_pid -O summary=basic,unit=KB
 Pid      Command          Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual
 4391290  ?????            596480    41900        0   577796
```

... which makes no sense because "that method", moves some elements from a hash table, inserts them in a new one, and then pushes it at the end of a deque of hash tables. Each hash saved in that queue holds no more than 100 elements each, where each element is basically a pointer. So, no way the execution of that method has added almost 100KiB.

Also, it confuses me a lot that the `Inuse` memory is bigger than the `virtual` memory.

What can be the cause of that mismatch in memory consumption?

My original guess was that the OS has just assigned or preallocated a new memory page for the process, but if that were the case, it makes no sense that more pages are added at each call of that very same method.